# Error while creating a User Defined Function in postgreSQL using SQL language

Tags: sql, postgresql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create the following  SQL(the only language I need for my use case) User Defined Function in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE function sql_replace(textinput text,pattern character,lefttext integer,righttext integer)
    returns text AS $$
    DECLARE strlength integer default 0;
    BEGIN
        strlength = length($1);
        return substr($1,1,$3 )
        ||regexp_replace(substr($1,$3+1,(strlength-$3-$4)),'[0-9]',$2)
        ||substr($1,(strlength-$4+1),$4 );
    -- Additional logic
    END;
    $$ language SQL VOLATILE;
```

I have been encountering an error near line 3 in the declare statement. I have tried to push the declare statement inside the begin block but it didn't help. I have also tried to align the input type with SQL but got the same error.

[image: error as indicated by the PostgreSQL shell]

Comment: `declare` is only valid in PL/pgSQL. And variables can also only be used in PL/pgSQL, you need to change `language sql` to `language plpgsql`.  There is also no need to reference parameters with numbers. That's what parameter names are for

Comment: Hi, I need the language to be SQL only(use case dependent). Is there any alternative for declaring a local variable in SQL.

Comment: You will have to repeat the expression `length(textinput)` in the `substr()` and `regexp_replace()` calls